# The number of homomorphism f from $(Z,+)$ to $(Q^{*},.)$ such that $f(2)=\frac{1}{3}$ .

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

How to count the number of homomorphism f from $(Z,+)$ to $(Q^{*},.)$ such that $f(2)=\frac{1}{3}$ ?

Can u tell me the way or algorithm to do find that ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The group $(\mathbb{Z},+)$ is generated by the single element $1$. If we know where it goes, we know everything about the homomorphism. So, then, what can we send $1$ to in $(\mathbb{Q}^*,\cdot)$ so that $2$ goes to $\frac13$? Well, $f(1+1)=f(1)\cdot f(1)$, so we would then need $f(1)^2=\frac13$. There are no rational square roots of $\frac13$, so there are no such homomorphisms.